# Android: Listen for notification update

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is there a way to listen if a notification is updated. For example if I receive a message in Messenger my notification listener will notice that, but once I receive a second message - the notification listener ignores that.

I have tried with cancelling notifications, but that did not work

My notification listener:

```
public class Reader extends NotificationListenerService{
     @Override
        public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
                int id = sbn.getId();
                String ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
                Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
                final String title = extras.getString("android.title");

                String tag = sbn.getTag();
                int ides = extras.getInt("android.id");
                final String ss = extras.getString("android.text").toString();
                final String text = ss.toLowerCase();
                if (pack.equals("com.facebook.orca")) {
    String e = "Tah";
                Log.e(e, pack);
                Log.e(e, ticker);
                Log.e(e, title);
                Log.e(e, ss);

                Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
                msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
                msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
                msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
                msgrcv.putExtra("text", ">" + text + "");

                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);
            }
        }
```

Comment: could I see your notification code?

Comment: Can I see the sender? That's the more important bit :D

Comment: The sender? You mean when I push the Notification?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct

Comment: Oh, no - I am not creating notifications, I am only reading them. Have you seen the app AirDroid? Something like that is what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: no, i havn't sadly :( sorry buddy. maybe you need to tailor the question more towards airdroid and you'll get a better response